# What's the best solution to get the result of a submission form in real time?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, web-services, server-side

I put the data on my website and using this data **in real time**, I want the results if I was completing the form on other websites.
I complete my form and I get the results from X websites.

I would like to know how to complete the forms in real time (which techno). 
Scraping the results is the easier part :)

Regards

Comment: Are you saying that your form mimics the form on another site and that you want to fill out the form on that other site (and get the results) when the user submits your form?..  also you emphasize the phrase "in real time" a lot, but it is ambiguous... what exactly do you mean by "in real time"?.. for example 200 years is a real value of time and so is 2 seconds...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I just want to aggregate several results without completing several forms on several websites.
"real time" because I would like to get the others results quickly after my submission.

Comment: submitting a form can be a very complicated task... this [page](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/mechanize/) might help to give you a clear idea of how you would go about it if you were going to use ruby/rails...  you will have to wait on the response from each form that you are submitting in addition to processing and submitting your form... so I would advise upon successful processing of your form redirecting to a webpage that makes ajax calls to the server to find out the status of each form you are submitting, or something of the sort...

Comment: Thank for your answer !
Do you think it can be easier to use something else than Ruby/Rails to do that?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... there are lots of gems you can use that will implement a lot of the functionality you need for you.. though I'm not aware of a gem that does everything you want

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "completing the forms in real-time"? Do you mean getting the results without a page refresh? You would use AJAX for that.